# How do I send a message to a specific channel in discord.js?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

***READ EDIT AT BOTTOM, CHANGES THE ENTIRE QUESTION.***

Yes, I know that people have asked this before. However, I can't find a solution that works and has not been deprecated. Here is the parts of my code that is required to operate the specific function I'm trying to replicate;

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const bot = new Discord.Client();
const client = bot

const token = 'NunyaBuisness';
const channel = '525723958239852735' // Not a real channel ID
const PREFIX = '.';

bot.on('message', msg=>{
    let args = msg.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(" ");
    switch(args[0]){
        case 'process':
            if(args[1] === 'test'){
                var testGuild = new Discord.Guild(bot, 'serverID');
                var testTextChannel = new Discord.TextChannel(testGuild, channel);
                testTextChannel.send("Test");
            }
        break;
    }
})
```

Bot returns the following on the message

> .process test

```
B:\bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\Guild.js:152
    this.large = Boolean('large' in data ? data.large : this.large);
                                 ^

TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'large' in serverID
    at Guild._patch (B:\bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\Guild.js:152:34)
    at new Guild (B:\bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\Guild.js:92:12)
    at Client.<anonymous> (B:\bot\index.js:101:33)
    at Client.emit (events.js:311:20)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (B:\bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:31:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (B:\bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (B:\bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:386:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (B:\bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:435:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (B:\bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:293:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (B:\bot\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:120:16)
```

Thanks for your help! I really appreciate it. I've been trying to solve this for days myself using the documentation but *constantly* fail.

***EDIT***

I believe the problem is that the method CLIENT.channels.get('id') literally doesn't exist. This is weird as hell and I'm looking through the GitHub to see if anything is missing. At this moment, I see absolutely nothing missing. This is super weird.
Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: Please indicate which line is 101. I suspect it is `var testGuild = new Discord.Guild(bot, 'serverID');`

Comment: Looks like you're passing a string where an object is expected. [Documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=afkChannel) says it should be `new Discord.Guild(client, data);` and that `data` should be an Object, but I'm not really sure what it should contain. There's an example [here](https://discordjs.guide/sharding/extended.html#using-functions-continued) which retrieves `data` from another call, but it's not clear why or what that code does

Comment: Why you use method `new Discord.Guild(` and `new Discord.TextChannel` for get a channel ?

Comment: @Cipher I seriously have no clue. I just gave up and put in the sample code I had at the time. I just want something like "channel = somefunction(channelID)"

Comment: So i add answer to your question :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For discord v12 change:

`msg.guild.channels.get(myChannel)` to `msg.guild.channels.cache.get(myChannel)`

```js
let myChannel = '123213123'

    bot.on('message', msg=>{
        let args = msg.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(" ");
        switch(args[0]){
            case 'process':
                if(args[1] === 'test'){
                    let targetChannel = msg.guild.channels.get(myChannel)
                    if (targetChannel) targetChannel.send('sssss')
                }
            break;
        }
    })
```

Comment: Hi! Did not read this correctly. This has been marked as the correct answer. Sorry!